# Error in adding a SharePoint page to "Embedded Webpage" widget in TFS

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I have a html content added to a SharePoint via "script editor" webpart. Now I am trying to add this page to a "Embedded Webpage" widget in TFS and getting an error as in the screenshot. Can someone help me to fix this.[image]

**Edit:** My SharePoint page is on HTTPS. After embedding it in the widget, the console logs the error as in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Embedded web page
>
> Only webpages that allow **[iframe embedding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)** are supported.
>
> [Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/widget-catalog#embedded-web-page)

According to the error info `this content cannot be displayed in a frame`. Make sure your html content webpage is following the syntax.